# Does 'fetch' method present the same functionality as 'FileReader'?

Tags: javascript, fetch, filereader

I managed to read the text file byte by byte and to change the charset from windows-1251 to Unicode for a file loaded from the end user's computer via an `input` element and `FileReader`. Now I want to do the same thing for a file from my server, via `fetch`. Is it possible to do that? (The `fetch` would be in a page served via HTTP and the URL would be relative, e.g. `fetch("raw/graph_tab.txt")` — I'm not trying to read a file directly from the end user's machine as I was with an `input` field and `FileReader`).

Chunks of working code (['windows-1251.js'](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/windows-1251) library is created by Mathias Bynens):

```
<input type="file" id="file"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("file").addEventListener("change", readFile, false);

        function readFile (evt) {
            var files = evt.target.files;
            var file = files[0];           
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(event) {
                console.log(windows1251.decode(event.target.result));            
            }};
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank for your explanation! May I ask for further clarification: you accented existing restrictions for one method 'FileReader'. I see it. But fetch method does not have such a restriction, it could read any source inserted manually in the code. So the question is about the ability of fetch method to proccess the binary fetched data in a way as it can make FileReader method.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder excuse my persistence, but I can't get the idea) Fetch method can take local path relative to default folder, you could see what I mean here https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21650814. Or I am wrong?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I feel you're my last straw) I completely get the idea now. But may I take the courage to repeat the question from the topic title? For my case the issue is that I perfectly process the binary data through FileReader but cannot understand how to get the same result by fetch method through web server...

Comment: Do you have a non-`file://` URL to the file? I mean, once any relative URL has been resolved, does the absolute URL start with `http://` or `https://`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes I do! Apache server is raised locally, java script code is executed on local index.html page. `fetch("raw/graph_tab.txt").then(function(response) {console.log(response.url);});` gives me http://localhost:8080/raw/graph_tab.txt in console. The target file is opened then normally when the link is clicked...

Comment: There's an important line missing from your `FileReader` example: What method are you calling to do the read? `readAsArrayBuffer`? `readAsBinaryString`? `readAsDataURL`? `readAsText`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean you want to have the `encoding` parameter of the `FileReader.readAsText(Blob, encoding)` method, then you'd set a [`charset` parameter](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/http-charset/index#charset) in the `Content-Type` header of your response.

If this is not doable for whatever reason, then you'd have to consume your [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object to a Blob using its [*Body.blob()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/blob) method, and then pass the resulting *Blob* to a FileReader.

Otherwise, no, even though the *Response* object has similar methods than the ones of a *FileReader*, the `text()` method doesn't provide an *encoding* option...

Comment: Technically, at Chromium/Chrome (not yet implemented at Mozilla browsers) `Body` has `.getReader()` method which returns a `ReadableStream`, where `.read()` can be called to get a `Uint8Array` output `(async() => {
  const response = await fetch('text.txt');
  const reader = await response.body.getReader();
  const {value} = await reader.read();})()` if the actual text is the expected output `TextDecoder()` could be used `const text = new TextDecoder().decode(value)`.

Comment: @guest271314 good to see you back. Yes they can also just do it with the Response.arrayBuffer result, or even use a FileReader with Response.blob result, no need for ReadableStream.

Comment: The only reason commented here was due to last sentence at _"doesn't provide an encoding option...". Technically `value` is a `Uint8Array` representation of the string, that is `"abc"` -> `[97, 98, 99]`

Comment: @guest271314 I feel there is a misconception here, the Uint8Array doesn't provide any info about the encoding, and while some encodings will indeed map to ASCII, any non-ASCII character will have different values, for instance `é` in ISO-Latin-1 is represented by a single byte `[233]`, whereas in UTF-8, it is represented as two bytes `[195, 169]`. So using a TextDecoder + ArrayBuffer is indeed possible, but you'd still need to pass the encoding parameter to it, since the default is UTF-8.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't have to do this conversion at all: You're running a web server, which apparently isn't correctly identifying the encoding of the file. It should correctly identify it in the `Content-Type` header it returns (e.g.: `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=windows-1251`). See [this article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by SO's own Joel Spolsky for more information.

If you can't do that for some reason: You can read the file as binary and get an `ArrayBuffer` for it via [`arrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/arrayBuffer) on the `fetch` response:

```
fetch("raw/graph_tab.txt")
.then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(response.status);
    }
    return response.arrayBuffer();
})
.then(buffer => {
    // ...convert it here...
})
.catch(error => {
    // Handle/report error
});
```

So then the question is what we do for `...convert it here...`. :-) The library you're referring to expects to get a "byte string" which I'm guessing is the same as what you'd get from the `readAsBinaryString` method of `FileReader`. If so, you can convert the `ArrayBuffer` to that format like this:

```
const str = new Uint8Array(buffer).map(byte => String.fromCharCode(byte)).join("");
```

So:

```
fetch("raw/graph_tab.txt")
.then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(response.status);
    }
    return response.arrayBuffer();
})
.then(buffer => {
    const str = new Uint8Array(buffer).map(byte => String.fromCharCode(byte)).join("");
    console.log(windows1251.decode(str));
})
.catch(error => {
    // Handle/report error
});
```

Comment: @t-j-crowder thank for your answer! Finally I got the way how to tune little bit your proposal for to make it working, here's the code: `const str = new Uint8Array(buffer).map(function(byte) {result += String.fromCharCode(byte);});`

Comment: Than `console.log(windows1251.decode(result));` It works!!! Probably the issue was in the mapping - one cannot have string values as input for Uint8Array. I couldn't make transfer to another simple array accepting string values from callback function, but text variable made it fine. Thank again!!!